# Rundeck permission denied while executing Script step invoked using sudo

Tags: sudo, rundeck

My rundeck job is configured with a single script step that is configured to be invoke using sudo. The execution preview for the script step in job configuration ui shows:
`sudo -u ${option.mysudouser} scriptfile`

On job run, I am getting below error:

> [sudo] password for < my ssh user>:
>
> sudo: unable to execute /tmp/< XXX>-dispatch-script.tmp.sh: Permission denied

On analysis I found that the **/tmp/< XXX>-dispatch-script.tmp.sh** file that is getting scp'd by rundeck to my node host is not having execute perms for all. Unfortunately < my ssh user> and my < sudo user> are different and do not share group. So, the job run fails with Permission issue since the temp file having the script couldn't be invoked as the sudo user.

Can anybody suggest:
* If rundeck provides any configuration value to determine the permissions of the temporary script file being created.
* Any other workarounds:
I have already tried as specifying the script as below but they don't solve the issue:
- chmod 777 /tmp/*-dispatch-script.tmp.sh;sudo -u ${option.mysudouser} scriptfile

- chmod 777 /tmp/*-dispatch-script.tmp.sh && sudo -u ${option.mysudouser} scriptfile

Please suggest how I can resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your rundeck account require sudo password to run `sudo -u ${option.mysudouser}`. If you can configure rundeck account on you target node, so that it doesn't require password for sudo. you should be good.

If you can not change sudoer file on the target node. you can use `${option.mysudouser}` as the execution user.

[Defining a node](http://rundeck.org/docs/administration/project-setup.html#defining-a-node)

`<project>
    <node name="orion" description="a foodazzler service host" tags="staging,us-east" psFamily="unix" osName="Linux" hostname="orion" ssh-authentication="password" ssh-password-option="option.password" username="${job.mysudouser}"
    />
</project>`

Comment: Link is dead :(